# Alexa skills console returns null

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I've written simple aws lambda code to output on the alexa skills kit console, but I'm constantly getting an output of null. I've made sure to paste the arn from aws lambda into the endpoint of the skill. Not sure why this is happening.

[aws lambda code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cj3u.png)

[alexa skills json output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kbult.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to properly form your responses to see them working on the Alexa Skill Kit Console. Passing a single string to the alexa service will not work. You could potentially use console.log outputs to see that the lambda call is working properly. You can also test under lambda's built-in test. A string output returns null because the alexa skill kit console requires a properly JSON formatted output. I'd suggest you to start with a sample hello world skill [example](https://github.com/alexa/skill-sample-nodejs-hello-world)